# Is Chrome supposed to transfer HTML5 video from the server in chunks?

Tags: google-chrome, safari, html5-video, charles-proxy

While looking at network traffic in Charles 3.6.3, we noticed that every time we invoke a `VIDEO` element's `play` method in Chrome the browser hits the server to retrieve a varying amount of data (ranging anywhere from several bytes' worth to several megabytes' worth) whereas when we do the same thing in Safari there is no network traffic to and from the server (it loads the entire video up front).

Which one is correct behavior for HTML5 video?